# How to use boolean on mysql login procedure

Tags: php, mysql

[Procedure parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHbi.png)

```
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM customer
              WHERE usern = p_user AND password = p_pass)

                SET p_output = 1;
    ELSE
                SET p_output = 0;

END;
```

MySQL gives me the error 1064, it's in the output. How i can do that set correctly? I have to give values ​​to the p_output parameter? 
You can see how i did it in the image.

Thank you!

Comment: You could do this with a standard update query. Also please don't store plain text passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing both the `THEN` and the `END IF` for your `IF` clause. Try this:

```
BEGIN    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM customer
              WHERE usern = p_user AND password = p_pass) THEN
                SET p_output = 1;
    ELSE
                SET p_output = 0;
    END IF;    
END;
```